# Process Builder Immediate Action Field dropdown showing unfamiliar fields

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, process-automation

I am doing the challenge for https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder# and I created a process builder for this.
In "immediate actions", I could see contact object fields. I was looking for AccountId in this list. But to my surprise, I could just see the account number. Where does this account number (and for same reason) other fields from this dropdown come from? 
I don't have Account Number as a field on Contact object and this dropdown should be showing fields from the contact fields ideally.
Please see below image which speaks my try.

**EDIT-**
[This](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtJMVnpeIImNghBXLMOzjQQMdwNF?e=iYqGJ3) is what the dropdown list has and [these](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtJMVnpeIImNghESHN_P3dbyrtrf?e=fLWX5L) are the fields at contact object. I agree that I have account number in contact object but then there are many other discrepancies in these two tables.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and I can't repro your experience. Are you sure you don't have a formula field on Contact called `Account Number`?

Comment: Edited the question. I can see account number but still not clear about the rest of the fields from this table. Shouldn't these two tables be in sync- what is being shown on UI and the actual fields of contact object.

Answer (score 0):

Account Name should be mapped with AccountId in Contact Object. See attached screenshot.

[image: Account Id on Contact Object]

Pleas navigate to contact object and verify.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: What it shows is just account number. Contact object does not has account number anywhere still it shows account number. how and from where?

Comment: I have tested in my dev org and all the fields are default; none created; Looks like your dev org has been used for some other purpose as well; can you check the field access? just verify you have access to all fields.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are as expected.  When you update the child `Contact` records, you will be presented with a list of fields with these exceptions:

- audit fields (like `CreatedById`, label `Account Name`)
- autonumber fields
- fields your profile doesn't have FLS for
- the lookup to the Account itself (`AccountId`, label `Account Name`)

that you can set. Your [link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtJMVnpeIImNghBXLMOzjQQMdwNF?e=iYqGJ3) shows fields on Contact object (like `MailingStreet`)

*I'm a bit surprised `Account Number` appears as that is a formula field and you can't set that to any value.*

The challenge in Trailblazer states:

> The process must have an Update Records action that updates Contact mailing address fields (Street, City, State, Postal Code, Country) when the parent Account shipping address field values are updated

So ...

- your decision block must test when Account Shipping Address changes
- your action block does Update Records for Account.Contacts and *unconditionally* sets the value of Contact.MailingAddress fields to Account.ShippingAddress fields

Comment: I tried doing experiment with formula fields of type date and number. Both appear in this list. So I guess formula fields appear in that list of contact fields. And if lookup fields don't appear then as per your answer, it is impossible for someone to create process builder unless he has a formula field looking up relationship. Becasue AccountId won't appear in that list so we must have a formula field (like I have) to look up account number. Please comment.

Comment: @lovegupta i'm confused by your question. The PB action is updating existing children Contact for the triggered Account. Every contact sibling gets the same value from a source value, where source value comes from the parent account (or its lookups), or from constants, or from formula expressions

Comment: Can you plz let me know what is the confusion. This challenge is asking that whenever an account is updated then its contacts should get mailing fields updated by the shipping values which are for corresponding account. So i created a PB on account and said that whenever account is updated then update  mailing fields of all contacts by account shipping fields. The criteria to chosse what all contacts to update is - contact.account number (THIS IS THE DROPDOWN IN QUESTION) = account.account number. The fields in the dropdown which has contact fields is the cause of this question.

Comment: Further to clarify on very first comment on this answer. I experimented with formula fields and all formula fields are coming in this dropdown. I can not think of a way of creating this PB if formula fields from contact object stop to appear in first dropdown which is in question. So I think your answer should not include formula fields into exceptions because formula fields do appear in the dropdown.

Comment: @lovegupta - updated answer